# Why nested promises are not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, promise

can someone try to fix my problem?

I am trying to get this output:

```
100x do C
done B
done A
```

But everytime i get this one:

```
10x do C
done B
done A
```

Is it possible to get it without using async/await feature?

```js
function a() {
    let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
        b();
        myResolve()
    });

    myPromise.then(function() {
        console.log('done A')
    });
}

function b() {
    let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            c();
        }
    myResolve()
    });
    
    myPromise.then(function() {
    console.log('done B')
    });
}

function c() {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      console.log('do C')
    }
}

a()
```

Comment: There is nothing in your program that would cause "10x" **nor** "100x" to be printed. Do you mean to say that the string "do C" should be printed 100 times?

Comment: yes yes, but T.J. Crowder already solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not declaring `i`, so you're creating an *implicit global variable* that both `b` and `c` write to. (I wrote an article about these years ago: [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).)

In the below, I'm going to make it three runs of three instead of ten runs of ten, just so we can see it more clearly (and so I don't have to increase the size of the in-snippet console's history — it has an option for that, but I don't recall the details).

I strongly recommend using strict mode so that this is the error it always should have been. Here's your code in strict mode and with rejection handlers added:

```js
"use strict";

function a() {
    let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
        b();
        myResolve()
    });

    myPromise.then(function() {
        console.log('done A')
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
}

function b() {
    let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            c();
        }
        myResolve()
    });
    
    myPromise.then(function() {
        console.log('done B')
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
}

function c() {
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      console.log('do C')
    }
}

a()
```

If you declare `i` (in both places), you'll get the result you expect.

```js
function a() {
    let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
        b();
        myResolve()
    });

    myPromise.then(function() {
        console.log('done A')
    });
}

function b() {
    let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // ***
            c();
        }
        myResolve()
    });
    
    myPromise.then(function() {
        console.log('done B')
    });
}

function c() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // ***
      console.log('do C')
    }
}

a()
```

**but**, beware that the reason you're getting the output you're getting is that everything except the calls to the fulfillment handlers is **synchronous**. If instead of a `for` loop you were doing some asynchronous process, there's nothing preventing you from getting `done B` or `done A` before all of the work done by `c` is done, because there's nothing connecting those promises together.

Let's see that. Suppose we have an asynchronous version of `console.log` that waits 10ms before writing the log entry (but we'll use `console.log` to write out `done A` and `done B` immediately, so you can see when they ran):

```
function asyncLog(...msgs) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(...msgs);
            resolve();
        }, 10);
    });
}
```

Let's look at what happens:

```js
function asyncLog(...msgs) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(...msgs);
            resolve();
        }, 10);
    });
}

function a() {
    let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
        b();
        myResolve();
    });

    myPromise.then(function() {
        console.log('done A');
    });
}

function b() {
    let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            c();
        }
        myResolve()
    });
    
    myPromise.then(function() {
        console.log('done B')
    });
}

function c() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      asyncLog('do C');
    }
}

a();
```

Notice how things aren't connected to each other.

To connect them, you'd have to make `b` wait for `c`'s promise to be fulfilled, and make `a` wait for `b`'s promise to be fulfilled. Something like this:

```js
function asyncLog(...msgs) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(...msgs);
            resolve();
        }, 10);
    });
}

function a() {
    let myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(b());
    });

    return myPromise
    .then(() => {
        console.log('done A');
    });
}

function b() {
    let myPromise = Promise.resolve();
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        myPromise = myPromise.then(c);
    }
    
    return myPromise
    .then(() => {
        console.log('done B')
    });
}

function c() {
    let p = Promise.resolve();
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        p = p.then(() => asyncLog('do C'));
    }
    return p;
}

a()
.then(() => {
    console.log("all done");
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
});
```

Comment: Funny thing: the SO snippet output is 50x do C due to a limit in the tool, even if the function is correct :)

Comment: ah, i can bet that i would spend another 4hours fixing it... thanks

Comment: Yes XD small trick: open your browser dev tools, paste the code provided, press enter XD

Comment: @EmanueleScarabattoli - Thanks for flagging that up. There's a way to make it larger, but I just went with doing three runs of three instead. :-)

Comment: @Nathaz - FWIW, I've expanded the answer in a way I hope you find useful. Happy coding!